# Which is better: Implementing a Runable Interface or extending Thread Class

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Implementing Runnable vs. extending Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2782744/implementing-runnable-vs-extending-thread)

I am very much confused about the perfect answer in simple language for above question. In which scenario which is better and why. can anyone explain.

Answer (score 2):

The [Executor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html) classes talk in terms of `Runnable`, and for that reason alone I favour implementing the `Runnable` interface. You don't carry the baggage of having your code implicitly tied into a thread and frameworks can handle `Runnables` in whatever way they prefer.

Answer (score 1):

Use these simple rules:

1) If the main purpose of a class is to be a thread, then subclass Thread

2) If the main purpose of a class is not to be a thread (e.g.: a GUI component),
implement Runnable

3) Use Runnable when the thread class is already sub-classed by another class